# Redirecting back doesn't work anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having some truble redirecting my users to the previous page.

Here is an example of an update method in the movies controller.

```
def update
  @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
  if @movie.update_attributes(params[:movie])
    flash[:notice] = "The given movie is now updated."
  end
  respond_with(@movie, location: :back)
end
```

I'm getting this error.

`undefined method 'hash_for_back_url' for #<Module:0x00000103eeaaa8>` on the `respond_with` line.

I'm using Rails 3.1 rc1 with Ruby 1.9.

It works when doing something like this.

`respond_with(@movie, location: request.referer)`

Anyone knows why the `:back` argument won't work?

Comment: should't it be :location => :back?

Comment: @jaydel - You can use the new syntax with Ruby 1.9.

Comment: It might be worth trying the old syntax just to be sure it's not that...

Comment: Same thing when using `:location => :back`. Is this a bug?

Comment: I get undefined method `back_url'. Is request.referer the new way or is something broken with :back?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only solution that worked for me was the use of `request.referer`.

**Solution #1**

```
respond_with(@comment, location: request.referer)
```

**Solution #2**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :redirect_back

  def redirect_back(options = {})
    if request.referer
      redirect_to request.referer, options
    else
      redirect_to root_path, options
    end
  end
end

# View / controller

redirect_back notice: "Sending you back ... hopefully"
```

Comment: or simplify that helper to return the paths and use with respond_with: def redirect_back_path request.referer || root_path end

Answer (score 0):

In that case respond_with is expecting :location to be the result of a url helper method like in `respond_with(@movie, :location => movie_url(@movie))`

You probably should be using one of this methods instead:

- redirect to an information page with `redirect_to @movie`, which is equivalent to `redirect_to movie_path(@movie)`
- render the form again with the updated data with `render :action => :edit` (:edit represent the action used to display the form)

Comment: This solution depends on a `MoviesController#show` method, which doesn't exist in my case. The problem is that I don't know how the user got the `MoviesController#edit` page, but i still want to redirect the user back to the original page. I can for example have a edit link in 10 different places on my site.

Comment: On the edit method save the referer, and pass it to the update method via session or a hidden field. Then use it in a redirect_to or a respond_with if you need the @movie object.

Comment: I still think this should work automatically. Just using `location: :back` should be enough.

Comment: respond_with does not support location: :back. Use `redirect_to location: :back` instead.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
respond_with @movie do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to :back }
end
```

Lets you override the default html responder so that you can use `redirect_to :back`